# How to edit(using script) a psd file for sending it to multiple receivers

Tags: photoshop, editing, psd

I am having a PSD template which is like some invitation . I have to send that psd file as an Image.
But for every image we should include receivers name.[image]

is there any script or process which asks just names as input and generates my JPEG images for every individual name as output.

ThankYou

Comment: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/25/introduction-to-photoshop-scripting/ - and all-caps topics is bad form, it's like SHOUTING!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following snippet to read your names from an external text file.

```
var file = new File( /c/folder/file.txt );       
file.open("r");
var str = file.read();
```

Then loop through those values and use the next snippet to find and replace the text in your document.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

for (var j= 0; j < doc.artLayers.length; j++) {
    var lyr = doc.artLayers[j];

    if (lyr.kind == LayerKind.TEXT) {
        var lyr = doc.artLayers[j];
        lyr.textItem.contents = lyr.textItem.contents.replace("search","replace"); 
    }
 }
```

And the last snippet will save out a jpg.

```
    var options = new JPGSaveOptions();
    var outputFile = new File(destPath + sourceFile.name.match(/(.+)\.[^\.\/]+$/)[1] + i + '.jpg');

    app.activeDocument.saveAs(outputFile, options);
```